# Adele : There's such a difference between us and a million miles

Tags: meaning

What the song writer was trying to say by *a million miles*?

> Hello, it's me I was wondering if after all these years you'd like to
>   meet To go over everything They say that time's supposed to heal ya
>   But I ain't done much healing
>
> Hello, can you hear me I'm in California dreaming about who we used to
>   be When we were younger and free I've forgotten how it felt before the
>   world fell at our feet
>
> **There's such a difference between us And a million miles**
>
> Hello from the other side I must have called a thousand times To tell
>   you I'm sorry for everything that I've done But when I call you never
>   seem to be home
>
> Hello from the outside At least I can say that I've tried To tell you
>   I'm sorry for breaking your heart But it don't matter it clearly
>   doesn't tear you apart anymore
>
> Hello, how are you? It's so typical of me to talk about myself I'm
>   sorry I hope that you're well Did you ever make it out of that town
>   where nothing ever happened
>
> It's no secret that the both of us Are running out of time
>
> So hello from the other side I must have called a thousand times To
>   tell you I'm sorry for everything that I've done But when I call you
>   never seem to be home Hello from the outside At least I can say that
>   I've tried To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart But it don't
>   matter it clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore
>
> Ooooohh, anymore Ooooohh, anymore Ooooohh, anymore Anymore
>
> Hello from the other side I must have called a thousand times To tell
>   you I'm sorry for everything that I've done But when I call you never
>   seem to be home Hello from the outside At least I can say that I've
>   tried To tell you I'm sorry for breaking your heart But it don't
>   matter it clearly doesn't tear you apart anymore

Comment: Literary analysis and song interpretation are rather unsuitable to the StackExchange format, and are explicitly off-topic. There are many other websites that discuss poem or song meanings, however. Please review the [help] regarding what is considered on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There's such a difference between us. And [there are] a million miles [between us].

By saying *there's a million miles between us*, the author means that two people are very different; they are not like-minded.

Comment: Can we say it is like saying **'we are worlds apart'**?

Comment: @haha Yes, same meaning.

Comment: You may want to use the word *hyperbole* in there somewhere.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Depends on if they're an astronaut, or if they're dead - in which case it may be difficult to measure ... :)